# PHP acting weird on my program

Tags: php, casting, echo

Today i started writing a small PHP code and it left me confusing and so i parked here.

```
<?php
echo (int) ((0.5 + 0.3) * 10); // Outputs 8 as expected

<?php
echo (int) ((0.1 + 0.7) * 10); // Outputs 7 . How ????
```

Can someone answer with a detailed explanation ?

Comment: Welcome to the world of floating point on computers

Comment: aaah, the joy of floating numbers ( 0.7 is actually something like 0.69999999999999 ) - edit: and casting in php? isnt this somekind of looked down on? I mean most people argue that type-free is the most awfsome ( awfull + awesome ) thing in php

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439140/int0-10-710-7-in-several-languages-how-to-prevent-this for detailed answer.

Comment: echo  (int) (0.1 + 0.7) * 10;

Comment: I find this one: http://floating-point-gui.de/ better than the Oracle one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because floating point representation in computers is not exact for some numbers. As already said in the comments, `0.7` is represented internally as `0.699999` or so.

There are two websites that continuously pop up in these kind of questions:

1. http://floating-point-gui.de/
2. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

I prefer the first one, as it is a little lighter on the academics. Read that information and you'll understand.