# php return wrong value

Tags: php

I am trying to calculate this in php :

```
echo (int)((0.1 + 0.7) * 20);
```

**why it return 15**

**Expected result:** 16

**Actual result**:15

Comment: almost certain to be a floating point rounding error.

Comment: why do you have jquery tag here ?? removing it

Comment: because some jquery user may help me that

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP unexpected result of float to int type cast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385685/php-unexpected-result-of-float-to-int-type-cast)

Comment: I'm guessing it is because (0.1+0.7) *20 returns 15.9999998 and converting a float to int always rounds down

Comment: I cannot actually get this. For 0.8,0.6,0.5.... it works correct.. Why not for 0.7+0.1????

Comment: Because 0.7 can not be represented exactly by a float number.

Comment: @urzeit can you explain it or refer a link for your answer.All can be benefitted from that

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP acting weird on my program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18712401/php-acting-weird-on-my-program)

Comment: @Ganesh: see chumkiu's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From doc: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

> Floating point numbers have limited precision. Although it depends on the system, PHP typically uses the IEEE 754 double precision format, which will give a maximum relative error due to rounding in the order of 1.11e-16. Non elementary arithmetic operations may give larger errors, and, of course, error propagation must be considered when several operations are compounded.
>
> Additionally, **rational numbers that are exactly representable as floating point numbers in base 10, like 0.1 or 0.7, do not have an exact representation as floating point numbers in base 2, which is used internally, no matter the size of the mantissa**. Hence, they cannot be converted into their internal binary counterparts without a small loss of precision. This can lead to confusing results: for example, floor((0.1+0.7)*10) will usually return 7 instead of the expected 8, since the internal representation will be something like 7.9999999999999991118....

you can use [BC Math Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php)

```
$precision = 2;
echo bcmul( bcadd("0.1","0.7",$precision) ,"20",$precision); // 16.00
```

Answer (score 1):

you need

```
intval ((0.1 + 0.7) * 20);
```

sorry, it's wrong, but here is a workaround:

```
$n= ( (0.1 + 0.7) * 20);  //=16
$n2 = intval ($n."");     // cast it to string, then to int.
echo $n2;
```

Comment: It does exactly the same

Comment: (0.1 + 0.7) * 20  = 16, which is ok, so why to use casting at all?

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by converting the decimals to their binary equivalent by PHP, this results in a loss of precision.

If you need a high degree of accuracy, use [GMP](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.php) or the [bcmath](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) library instead.

Answer (score 0):

Type casting the result is leading to a wrong number `echo ((0.1 + 0.7) * 20);` should give 16

Comment: yes it working fine but what about floating to integer type casting?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a rounding error

0.1 + 0.7 = 0.7999999999

0.799999999 * 20 = 15.9999998

int(15.9999998) = 15

you have to round the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo (int)(((0.1*10 + 0.7*10)/10) * 20);
```

First you need to get rid of the decimal then perform the operation
else don't typecast

```
echo (0.1+0.7)*20;
```

Comment: don't typecast float to int.

Answer (score 0):

did you try this approach? :

```
<?php
$value = (0.1+0.7)*20;
echo $value;
?>
```

my result is **16**

Comment: yes it working fine but what about floating to integer type casting?

Comment: You don't have to cast the result to an integer, because as soon as you print it with echo it gets transformed into its string representation. If you want to round the result, use round().

Answer (score 0):

Please read [PHP documentation on foating point numbers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php). As is written in the documentation,

> For example, floor((0.1+0.7)*10) will usually return 7 instead of the expected 8.

When working with floating point numbers, use [BC Math](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) to get correct results.

Answer (score 0):

Use [round](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php).

```
echo round((0.1 + 0.7) * 20);
```

**Output**

```
16
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's be more precise:

```
printf("%1\$.20f", 0.7); // output: 0.69999999999999995559
printf("%1\$.20f", 0.1); // output: 0.10000000000000000555
printf("%1\$.20f", (0.10000000000000000555+0.69999999999999995559)*20); // output: 15.99999999999999822364
```

so when you cast the last number to int :

```
echo (int)15.99999999999999822364; // output: 15
```